# Add new rows to a matrix subdiagonal in R using vector values

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I am writing a function to create a matrix which has the following structure. The most important thing to note is that rows 2 - 7 contain a value the subdiagonal and 0's in all other columns:

```
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.50 0.50
0.75 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.80 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.80 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.90 0.00 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.60 0.00 0.00
0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00 0.80 0.00
```

There are two inputs to my function, `x` and `y`.  The first row is defined by the `x` vector such that:

```
x <- c(0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.50, 0.50)
```

I would like to use the second vector `y` to complete the rest of the matrix.  By using the first value in R2 C1, the second value in R3 C2, the third value in R4 C3 and so on until the matrix is completed and then fill everything else with 0's.

```
y <- c(0.75, 0.80, 0.80, 0.90, 0.60, 0.80, 0.00)
```

I'm sure this can be solved in R, perhaps there is already a matrix function to define this structure or a for loop could be used.

I can write the function, create the matrix and add the first line (see below) but the next bit is slightly beyond my current skill set - the function needs to be dynamic - ie. the values of x and y and length may change.

Any assistance or pointers from anyone would be appreciated..

(This is what I have so far.... I know it's a bit pathetic)

```
matrix <- function (x, y) {
   matrix <- x

   matrix
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt all in one go:

```
head(rbind(x, diag(y)),-1)
```

This basically creates a square matrix from `y` with the values on the `diag`onal, pushes it down by one row by `rbind`-ing `x`, then drops the extra row from the bottom of the newly created matrix.

Or a bit of creative indexing using `row` and `col` can do it too:

```
m <- matrix(0,nrow=7,ncol=7)
m[row(m)-col(m)==1] <- head(y,-1)
m[1,] <- x
```

Both returning:

```
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,] 0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.5  0.5
#[2,] 0.75  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#[3,] 0.00  0.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#[4,] 0.00  0.0  0.8  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
#[5,] 0.00  0.0  0.0  0.9  0.0  0.0  0.0
#[6,] 0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.6  0.0  0.0
#[7,] 0.00  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.8  0.0
```

Comment: I like that -  very clever, I'll take the all in one go answer! Thanks for your help.

Comment: you might not want row names, so maybe `unname(x)` in that first line

Comment: @shayaa - Or `head(rbind(x, diag(y), deparse.level=0),-1)` if you want to use the formal argument that controls that.

Comment: Can the row names be removed as well?

Comment: @AlisonBennett - that's what the comments above are about - use `unname(x)` or my code including `deparse.level=0`